# problem with the table of content

Tags: table-of-contents

I have a problem in my PhD report :
in the introduction page, I got "sommaire" on top of page in place of "introduction". I try with \newpage   and \clearpage. But the i got always the same problem.

Any idea please. thank yu

Comment: Which documentclass do you use? What's in the `TitlePage` file? We don't have the code from this file. Please complete this to a compilable document, not a pile of fragments

Comment: \documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{StyleThese}

Comment: `StyleThese`? Never heard of this

Comment: ok, its impossible here to attach a file of the report class

Comment: You could use Dropbox?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vj778ha5avjg1y8/StyleThese.bst?dl=0

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qcnyb1swe8oyou6/StyleThese.cls?dl=0

Comment: @Fish: The `StyleThese.cls` is apparently a slightly modified `book.cls` file. If I use it and ignore the included `TitlePage` files, I get small case roman numbers for the `Remerciments` and arabic numbers for the `Introduction generale` -- what ever goes wrong, its hidden in the included files you did not show

Comment: Ok , i will put the project in dropbx. Thank you Christian

Comment: @ChristianHupfer  I edit the question

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/y3r2x3hlg8imlok/these.rar?dl=0

Comment: @Fish: I downloaded it, but there are compilation errors :-(

Comment: @Christian, yes but they dont affect on the table of content

Comment: @Fish: Well, it's annoying to find out the errors first :-(

Comment: perhaps try `\markboth {Introduction}{Introduction}`.

Comment: @jfbu Thank very much,the problem disappear , but Introduction does not appear in the table of content.

Comment: @jfbu Ok i did a mustake, tnak youuuuuu very much You save my life really. Cheers :)

Comment: The `These` file is a bunch of messy statements and wrong usages of `LaTeX` commands, especially the `formatAndDefs` file, which is `\included` -- don't use `\include` in the preamble. Use ``\input`, if really needed

Answer (score 1):

The problem may go away with adding

```
\markboth {Introduction}{Introduction}
```

at the suitable place.